# BitBucket Pipeline for Simple HTML site, no database

Tags: git, bitbucket, self-hosting, bitbucket-pipelines

Looking into using BitBucket Pipeline to automate a legacy client HTML website. Most tutorials for Pipelines expect Node or some sort of build process.

If I just want a Pipeline to push to a standard shared Apache server, over FTP, and git-push any changed HTML, CSS, and JS files to the live server - any tips? I really mean basic setup, the site doesn't even have a stage server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565246/push-from-bitbucket-repository-to-shared-hosting-ftp-server/40846548#40846548

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I have a similar setup, this is how my piplene file look like

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - echo "Everything is awesome!"

  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
            - git ftp push --user $FTP_USER --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD <ftp server>
```

here is the source I got the guide from

https://www.savjee.be/2016/06/Deploying-website-to-ftp-or-amazon-s3-with-BitBucket-Pipelines/

What I want to do here is just push the changes in "master" to the ftp server, works like a charme. The credentials are set as envornmental variables in bitbucket

```
FTP_USER
FTP_PASSWORD
```

You just need to take care to replace

```
git ftp push --user $FTP_USER --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD <ftp server>
```

with

```
git ftp init --user $FTP_USER --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD <ftp server>
```

for the very first build

Comment: I ended up finding the same script, and I can report its running perfectly on my setup. A real time saver.